# convert PSUTIL Process output to object/dict?

Tags: python, scripting, python-2.x, psutil, systemctl

I am currently running the following script to get the system_md status of each host. Its working but the output I am getting is a Process Class and I am not sure how to parse the following params to a usable dict. I do not use python much so any help would be great.

- convert:

```bash
 psutil.Process(pid=1153, name='sssd', status='sleeping', started='2022-09-22 19:36:12')>
```

to -

```py
obj = {
name:"somename",
pid: 1010,
status: "sleeping"
started:'2022-09-22
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import psutil


def log_running_services():
    known_cgroups = set()
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        try:
            cgroups = open('/proc/%d/cgroup' % pid, 'r').read()
        except IOError:
            continue  # may have exited since we read the listing, or may not have permissions
        systemd_name_match = re.search(
            '^1:name=systemd:(/.+)$', cgroups, re.MULTILINE)
        if systemd_name_match is None:
            continue  # not in a systemd-maintained cgroup
        systemd_name = systemd_name_match.group(1)
        if systemd_name in known_cgroups:
            continue  # we already printed this one
        if not systemd_name.endswith('.service'):
            continue  # this isn't actually a service
        known_cgroups.add(systemd_name)
        print(systemd_name)
        process = psutil.Process(pid)
      
       # Attempting to get dict with  dict.name = name etc. 
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_running_services()
```

Answer (score 0):

And I resolved it with the following code outputs pretty pretty json with the service and status name:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import psutil
import json


def log_running_services():
    known_cgroups = set()
    result = []
    # print(psutil.pids)
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        try:
            cgroups = open('/proc/%d/cgroup' % pid, 'r').read()
        except IOError:
            continue  # may have exited since we read the listing, or may not have permissions
        systemd_name_match = re.search(
            '^1:name=systemd:(/.+)$', cgroups, re.MULTILINE)
        if systemd_name_match is None:
            continue  # not in a systemd-maintained cgroup
        systemd_name = systemd_name_match.group(1)
        if systemd_name in known_cgroups:
            continue  # we already printed this one
        if not systemd_name.endswith('.service'):
            continue  # this isn't actually a service
        known_cgroups.add(systemd_name)
        s = "{0}".format(psutil.Process(pid))
        mydict = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in
                      (item.split('=') for item in s.split(',')))

        obj = {
            "name": eval(mydict.get("name")),
            "status": eval(mydict.get('status'))
        }
        result.append(obj)
    print(json.dumps(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_running_services()
```